# Can't update from official repositories [Error 409]

Tags: apt, updates, repository

I can't update from official repositories with any pc from my local network. I think I haven't changed anything from my router but I also got an error report sentece telling me official repository isn't signed:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  409  Conflict [IP: 104.19.139.75 80]
E: The repository 'http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is not signed.
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

What can I do? I haven't found anything useful on the Internet.

Comment: is this after a fresh install, or is this happening after youve been running your rig for a while?

Comment: @DPS I have been running updates after some time. It isn't a recent install.

Comment: hmm, i sometimes get this error when my wifi or internet is messing up or being unstable. rebooting has fixed it for me in the past, or even just disconnecting and reconnecting to my connection, then running `sudo apt update`.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors shows the evowise mirror is a day behind; you could switch to the main archive, switch to the main mirror, or raise a ticket with them.

Comment: I found the soulution in this post:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/314447/error-instalaci%C3%B3n-git-en-ubuntu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to go directly to ***Software & Updates → Ubuntu Software***. In that tab, where it says "download from" change the one you have (you will have the one from your country) and change it to Main Server, so you don't have to edit the sources.list file. After few days if you want to use the one in your country again (see if it works again) and if it does not continue with the main server if it does not give you problems.

Comment: Hey @louiesanchezdj!!! Since this is an English only site, all posts here are expected to be in English only. For now I have translated the post using online tools and lightly edited the post. If you aren't comfortable enough in English, you can always use online translation tools for example Google translate. Thanks :)